# Having errors on parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-intent

I'm trying to parse JSON from sdcard. When I try to execute to AsyncTask Simple Adapter, I'm getting following error:

```
The method execute(String...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Void,SimpleAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuilder)
```

I spent more than a week to solve this code but I couln't made it.
My code is:

```
public class Jeans extends Activity {
    private final String JSON_file = "country.json";
    File jsonFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.baby1_1);

        /** Getting Cache Directory */
        File cDir = ExternalStorage.getSDCacheDir( this, "json_files" );

        /** Getting a reference to temporary file, if created earlier */
        jsonFile = new File(cDir.getPath() + "/" + JSON_file) ;

        String strLine="";
        StringBuilder strJson = new StringBuilder();

        /** Reading contents of the temporary file, if already exists */
        try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

            /** Reading the contents of the file , line by line */
            while( (strLine=bReader.readLine()) != null  ){
                strJson.append(strLine);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     System.out.println(strJson);


        /** The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread */
       // ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

        /** In here i'm getting the error */
        new ListViewLoaderTask().execute(strJson);

    }


    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        /** Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread */
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

            List<HashMap<String, String>> countries = null;

            try{
                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }

            /** Keys used in Hashmap */
            String[] from = { "country","flag","details"};

            /** Ids of views in listview_layout */
            int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_country_details};

            /** Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            *  R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            */
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

            return adapter;
        }

        /** Invoked by the Android system on "doInBackground" is executed completely */
        /** This will be executed in ui thread */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            /** Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file */
            ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

            /** Setting the adapter containing the country list to listview */
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please someone solve this code for me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you aren't passing in a string.

Do:

```
    /** In here i'm getting the error */
    new ListViewLoaderTask().execute(strJson.toString());
```

Remember that when you are working with objects, you need to use the `toString()` method to create a string.

Comment: Blaine Please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302964/need-help-on-json-parsing-2-issues

Answer (score 6):

Wrong type, should be `String`:

```
new ListViewLoaderTask().execute(strJson.toString());
```